# Not Working Click to Zoom for Photos: Adding the Lightbox Effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, image, popup

Im add to my **image** to  **popup** script to following script, but not display popup image, popup view is working but not display any images please give me a solution ,thanks  [image: look at this]
**Style**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    a.fancybox img {
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -o-transform: scale(1,1); -ms-transform: scale(1,1); -moz-transform: scale(1,1); -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); transform: scale(1,1); -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    } 
    a.fancybox:hover img {
        position: relative; z-index: 999; -o-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -ms-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -moz-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -webkit-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
    }
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function($){
        var addToAll = false;
        var gallery = true;
        var titlePosition = 'inside';
        $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var title = $this.attr('title');
            var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
            var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
            $this.wrap(a);
        });
        if (gallery)
            $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
            titlePosition: titlePosition
        });
    });
    $.noConflict();
</script>
```

**html**

```
<td class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="@Url.Action("FileName", "Component", new { id = item.FileName })" alt="@item.FileName" style="width:20px; height:20px;" data-big="big-image.jpg" class="fancybox" />
                        </td>
```